# PHP - convert date to simple datetime?

Tags: php, datetime

My php client is consuming java soap web service with date parameter. The client is passing it in the following format:

```
2016-09-18
```

The server responds with:

```
javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException: java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2016-09-18' could not be parsed at index 10
```

as it expcts it in simple datetime format:

```
2016-09-18T00:00:00.000-0000
```

How can I convert it to simple datetime format in php ?

Comment: Maybe this is thinking too simply, but can you just append the string `"T00:00:00.000-0000"` to it?

Comment: This should do it: `$date = (new DateTime('2016-09-18'))->format('c');`

Comment: @Daan it worked, add it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

echo date('c', strtotime('2016-10-18'));

returns

2016-10-18T00:00:00-04:00

which is the ISO 8601 date, and might be acceptable.

Or roll your own date format after converting string-to-time, as in http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php.